# Account test for android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, multiplayer, google-play-games, adk

I have downloaded ButtonClicker app (https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples)

This game application use google play services.

I want to run  application with eclipse and local emulator. Are there account of test?

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to follow step by step guide in Google Game development[1](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart). There are more sample applications using google play service on that site. It helped me a lot to configure multiplayer, leader board in my game! Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I don't want to register yet before I could to test my app with the emulator. 
On the guide: Point your web browser to the Google Play Developer Console, and sign in. If you haven't registered for the Google Play Developer Console before, you will be prompted to do so.